# How to add rows that include formula in spreadsheet?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am working with a spreadsheet in OpenOffice. This spreadsheet already has the 
formulas for each row. I need to add additional rows to this spreadsheet, but don't
know how to do so in order that it copys the formula but applies it to that row.

For example, each row has 8 columns (A-H), and there are formulas in D,F,G,and H. The formulas apply to each row, for example the last row on the sheet is the 6th row, so the formulas read like: =+B6*C6, =+E6*B6, etc.

Lets say I need to add a 7th row that utilizes the same formulas, but don't want to have to manually enter it for each new row so that it applies (for example: =+B7*C7, etc) How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Normal copy and paste will do that. That's the beauty of a spreadsheet. Although the formula looks like it says "B6" it is actually stored internally as something like "three cells to the left" so when you copy it to the row below, it is still "three cells to the left" only it appears as B7.

Comment: I think that's the best answer, I looked at how to do this with LibreOffice and that's what I have to do. It would be nice if there could be a way to insert a row that automatically does that though.

Answer (score 2):

You can also select (click) the cell with the formula, then drag the little black square in the bottom right hand corner of your selection, down to repeat however many times you need it to.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way.
Select the entire row (clicking on the row number), hold Ctrl+Alt and drag the row to the line below. It will copy+insert the row.

You can also copy the entire row and "paste special" (Ctrl+Shift+V) selecting the option to shift the cells down

I just didn't find a way to insert many rows at once with the data.

(I now it´s an old post, but it´s to help people looking on Google)

Answer (score 1):

Excel tables auto fill formulas as new rows are added.
As easy as it sounds to copy/fill formulas down, it is usually beyond a users ability to either comprehend or remember to do the fill. OpenOffice/libre office, etc., needs to be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Although new rows with copied formulas can be inserted anywhere for any reason, these instructions assume that you have spreadsheet with many data rows. And above is/are header rows. And below is/are total rows. And it is your desire to add a row to the bottom of the data rows (immediately above the total rows) and that the data rows contain formulas you would like to copy. And the new data row is to applied to the total below.

The first time you do it... not so easy... After that... two clicks...

Select the row with the formulas by clicking the row number (the last data row).
Copy the row (Ctrl+C).
Press the down arrow (now on footer row possibly containing summation formulas).
Begin a special paste operation (Ctrl+Shift+V).
Change the "selection" check marks so that only "Formulas" is selected.
Chose "Down" in "Shift Cells".
Hit "OK" (or press Return) to inset the row.

Edit the summation formula (F2) and make sure the summation range is still correct. If it is not, then you can manually fix the range, but you really need to change the following LibreOffice setting:

Choose menu option "Tools" (Alt-T).
Choose "Options" (O) in the "Tools" menu.
Expand "LibreOffice Calc" (Hit the disclosure triangle there).
Select "General" in the "LibreOffice Calc" expansion list.
Put a checkmark in (click) the "Expand references when new columns/rows are inserted"

Now that you have the row in the copy buffer and proper setup is complete, you only need to be on the first footer row, press Ctrl+Shift+V and hit Return.

Comment: I wish it would work when I simply insert a new row (using a keyboard shortcut Ctrl and + or using the context menu on a row number). Copy&pasting formulas is a bit complicated but better than nothing. Thanks for the tip!